# Метод родительского класса не видит переменные дочернего

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть простенькая программа моделирование ПК игры. Есть родительский класс being и два дочерних humanlike и monsterlike. В being есть метод "атака". Когда я хочу применить это на практике то ничего не выходит (healthpoint монстра остаётся всегда прежним, т.к. подставляет в метод мусор вместо значений переменных доч. классов). Покопавшись я узнал что при использовании доч. класса сначала инициализируется род. класс а только потом дочерние, стало всё понятно. Но как исправить ситуацию все же не знаю.

Being.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class being
{
protected:
    std::string Name;
public:
    int strength;
    int endurance;
    int intelligence;
    int dexterity;
    float healthPoint;
    float magicResist;
    float physicalResist;
    float atackDamage;
    bool damageTypePhysical = true;
    void atack(being &being);
    void defense();
};
```

Being.cpp (отрывок метода)

```
void being::atack(being &being)
{
    float damageDone;
    if (damageTypePhysical)
    {
        damageDone = ((atackDamage + ((strength * 0.50) + (dexterity * 0.40))) - being.physicalResist);
    }
    else
    {
        damageDone = ((atackDamage + ((intelligence * 0.50) + (endurance * 0.40))) - being.magicResist);
    }
    if (damageDone < 0.0)
    {
        damageDone = 0.0;
        std::cout << "Fail. Your damage is less than enemy resistance." << std::endl;
    }
    being.healthPoint -= damageDone;
}
```

Humanlike.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Being.h"

class humanlike : public being
{
public:
    int strength = 5;
    int endurance = 5;
    int intelligence = 20;
    int dexterity = 8;
    int luck = 15;
    int charisma = 15;
    int money = 0;
    float healthPoint = 80;
    float magicResist = 30;
    float physicalResist = 15;
    float atackDamage = 15;
    bool run();
};
```

Monsterlike.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Being.h"
#include "Humanlike.h"

class monsterlike : public being
{
public:
    int strength = 15;
    int endurance = 10;
    int intelligence = 5;
    int dexterity = 8;
    int minions = 0;
    int animanlIstinct = 10;
    float healthPoint = 100;
    float magicResist = 15;
    float physicalResist = 30;
    float atackDamage = 20;
    void scream(humanlike &humanlike);
    void rabies(humanlike &humalike);
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Being.h"
#include "Humanlike.h"
#include "Monsterlike.h"
int main()
{
    humanlike Me;
    monsterlike Ogr;
    Me.atack(Ogr);
    std::cout << Ogr.healthPoint;
    return 0;
}
```

Всегда выдает "Fail. Your damage is less than enemy resistance.".

Comment: У вас поля дублируются. А базовый класс ничего даже не знает о дочерних.

Comment: @user7860670 Вы про характеристики персонажа? Просто я не знаю как указать дочернему классу что нужно исп. уже имеющиеся переменные из род. поэтому инициализировал их заново присвоив нужные значения.

Comment: Вам надо делать конструкторы и инициализировать все в них. *"поэтому инициализировал их заново"* - нет, вы создали еще один набор полей с теми же именами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объясню на примере класса `humanlike`. Он наследует все члены класса `being` и добавляет свои - данные `luck`, `charisma`, `money` и функцию `run`.
Только эти поля и должны быть в классе `humanlike`, а остальные члены надо инициализировать в конструкторе. Например так:

```
#pragma once
#include "Being.h"

class humanlike : public being
{
public:
    //Поля базового класса инициализируем в конструкторе по умолчанию
    humanlike() : strength(5), endurance(5), intelligence(20), dexterity(8)
      healthPoint(80), magicResist(30), physicalResist(15), atackDamage(15)
    {
    }

    //Поля своего класса инициализируем в их объявлениях
    int luck = 15;
    int charisma = 15;
    int money = 0;
    bool run();
};
```